# How to play a wav file from a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

Good afternoon. I'm making a small program on wpf. There is a ListBox in which wav files from a folder are loaded. There is a RadioButton (there are several of them), when you click on it, certain audio files are added to the list. But I do not know how to play the selected audio track when clicking on the wav element in the ListBox

```
        SoundPlayer player;
        string[] playList;
        private void сmClassic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbList.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\1395355\Desktop\Студент\C#\4_FourthProject\FourthProject\bin\Debug\music\classic");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.wav"); 
            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                lbList.Items.Add(fi.ToString());
            }
 
            string d = playList[lbList.SelectedIndex];
           // player.Open(d); Yes, there is a mistake, but I was looking for an alternative
            player.Play();
 
        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
 
        }
```

Comment: In your `SelectionChanged` event handler you can get the currently selected items by iterating over the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems` property of the `SelectionChangedEventArgs`  parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code from answer [in original source](https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2866623.html).

```cs
        private void сmClassic(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\1395355\Desktop\Студент\C#\4_FourthProject\FourthProject\bin\Debug\music\classic");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.wav"); 
            lbList.ItemsSource = files;
        }
```

```cs
        private readonly SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
 
        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Stop();
 
            if(lbList.SelectedItem is FileInfo file)
            {
                player.SoundLocation=file.FullName;
                player.PlaySync();
            }
            else
            {
               player.SoundLocation=null;
            }
        }
```